# Accessing other user’s files/browser cookies and logins on Mac with root access?

Tags: macos

I was wondering if the root user on a Mac (Mavericks) can freely access any other user account and use a browser like they do? This means being automatically logged in their browser with all cookies/accesses for Facebook, Emails etc without a need of entering the password. Does OS X support this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? As it stands you question is rather vague. If you log in as root, you will have access to any file on the machine; but opening it, if is under their keychain, will require that user's keychain password. Root isn't 'god'.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X your login credentials will be stored in Keychain by default. This can be accessed by the admin only.
For more reference you can refer [this](http://www.umkc.edu/is/support/services/macintosh/keychain.asp).

`

Comment: Thank you. This is what I tried, unfortunately there are only login credentials to my root account, not the login/passwords of other users on this Mac.

Comment: mac user credentials will not be stored in the keychain access. i think so .